# codigo compilado mediane tsc no reconoce rutas

Tags: typescript, backend, refactoring

estoy refactorizando mi backend y a la hora de compilar estoy obteniendo un error que no estaría entendiendo bien el motivo

**directorio**

```
  ├── dist
  ├── node_module
  ├── src
  ├──   ├── apollo
  ├──   ├── config
  ├──   ├── database
  ├──   ├── functiones
  ├──   ├── index.ts
  ├── .gitignore
  ├── .env
  ├── packege-lock.json
  ├── packege.json
  ├── tsconfig.json
```

en mi `tsconfig.json` tengo un `baseUrl` apuntando directamente al directorio `src`, el editor lo reconoce, las rutas las puedo manejar como quiero, `functions/jsonwebtoken.ts` (obviamente sin el `.ts`), el problema que recibo es una vez compilado el código, la consola me muestra lo siguiente

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'functions/jsonwebtoken'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\enzo_\Desktop\code\proyect\backend\dist\apollo\resolvers\authentication.resolver.js
- C:\Users\enzo_\Desktop\code\proyect\backend\dist\apollo\schemas.js
- C:\Users\enzo_\Desktop\code\proyect\backend\dist\apollo\index.js
- C:\Users\enzo_\Desktop\code\proyect\backend\dist\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\enzo_\Desktop\code\proyect\backend\dist\apollo\resolvers\authentication.resolver.js:8:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\enzo_\\Desktop\\code\\proyect\\backend\\dist\\apollo\\resolvers\\authentication.resolver.js',
    'C:\\Users\\enzo_\\Desktop\\code\\proyect\\backend\\dist\\apollo\\schemas.js',
    'C:\\Users\\enzo_\\Desktop\\code\\proyect\\backend\\dist\\apollo\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\enzo_\\Desktop\\code\\proyect\\backend\\dist\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

dejo el `tsconfig.json` para que puedan visualizarlo correctamente

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ES2020",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["ES2020", "esnext.asynciterable"],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./src",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,      /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "./src",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Qué versión de TypeScript estás usando?

Comment: @KBeDev `"typescript": "^4.2.3"`

Comment: Fíjate que según la estructura, no existe la carpeta `functions`, sin embargo, el archivo está llamando al módulo `functions/jsonwebtoken`. Lo más cercano a ello, sería la carpeta `functiones`